# Activity redirected error from LoginActivity to RegisterActivity

Tags: java, android

when the Textview "Register Here" on clicked, it should be redirect to Register Activity, but redirected on Main Activity. I don't know what's the prob. Could you please show me what's wrong? and how to solve the problem?

I do the following :

LoginActivity.java

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private EditText etusername, etpassword;
    private Button btnlogin;
    private TextView tvreg;
    private ParseContent parseContent;
    private final int LoginTask = 1;
    private PreferenceHelper preferenceHelper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        parseContent = new ParseContent(this);
        preferenceHelper = new PreferenceHelper(this);

        etusername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etusername);
        etpassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etpassword);

        btnlogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
        tvreg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvreg);

        tvreg.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnlogin.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
    private void login() throws IOException, JSONException {

        if (!Utils.isNetworkAvailable(LoginActivity.this)) {
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Internet is required!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        Utils.showSimpleProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);
        final HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put(Constants.Params.USERNAME, etusername.getText().toString());
        map.put(Constants.Params.PASSWORD, etpassword.getText().toString());
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>(){
            protected String doInBackground(Void[] params) {
                String response="";
                try {
                    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest(Constants.ServiceType.LOGIN);
                    response = req.prepare(HttpRequest.Method.POST).withData(map).sendAndReadString();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    response=e.getMessage();
                }
                return response;
            }
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                //do something with response
                Log.d("newwwss", result);
                onTaskCompleted(result,LoginTask);
            }
        }.execute();
    }

    private void onTaskCompleted(String response,int task) {
        Log.d("responsejson", response.toString());
        Utils.removeSimpleProgressDialog();  //will remove progress dialog
        switch (task) {
            case LoginTask:

                if (parseContent.isSuccess(response)) {

                    parseContent.saveInfo(response);
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Login Successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    this.finish();

                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, parseContent.getErrorMessage(response), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == tvreg){
            startActivity(new Intent(this, RegisterActivity.class));
        }

        if (v == btnlogin){
            try {
                login();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

RegisterActivity.java

```
public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText etname, ethobby, etusername, etpassword;
    private Button btnregister;
    private TextView tvlogin;
    private ParseContent parseContent;
    private PreferenceHelper preferenceHelper;
    private final int RegTask = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        preferenceHelper = new PreferenceHelper(this);
        parseContent = new ParseContent(this);

        if(preferenceHelper.getIsLogin()){
            Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
            this.finish();
        }

        etname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etname);
        ethobby = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ethobby);
        etusername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etusername);
        etpassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etpassword);

        btnregister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
        tvlogin = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvlogin);

        tvlogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this,LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        btnregister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    register();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    private void register() throws IOException, JSONException {
        if (!Utils.isNetworkAvailable(RegisterActivity.this)) {
            Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Internet is required!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        Utils.showSimpleProgressDialog(RegisterActivity.this);
        final HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put(Constants.Params.NAME, etname.getText().toString());
        map.put(Constants.Params.HOBBY, ethobby.getText().toString());
        map.put(Constants.Params.USERNAME, etusername.getText().toString());
        map.put(Constants.Params.PASSWORD, etpassword.getText().toString());
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>(){
            protected String doInBackground(Void[] params) {
                String response="";
                try {
                    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest(Constants.ServiceType.REGISTER);
                    response = req.prepare(HttpRequest.Method.POST).withData(map).sendAndReadString();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    response=e.getMessage();
                }
                return response;
            }
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                //do something with response
                Log.d("newwwss", result);
                onTaskCompleted(result, RegTask);
            }
        }.execute();
    }
    private void onTaskCompleted(String response,int task) {
        Log.d("responsejson", response.toString());
        Utils.removeSimpleProgressDialog();  //will remove progress dialog
        switch (task) {
            case RegTask:

                if (parseContent.isSuccess(response)) {
                    parseContent.saveInfo(response);
                    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Registered Successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    this.finish();
                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, parseContent.getErrorMessage(response), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
        }
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    private DrawerLayout drawer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        //setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar,
                R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                    new HomeFragment()).commit();
            navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.nav_home);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.nav_home:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
//The problem is redirected on HomeFragment
                        new HomeFragment()).commit();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_profile:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                        new ProfileFragment()).commit();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_myloc:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                        new MylocFragment()).commit();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_map:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                        new MapFragment()).commit();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_about:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                        new AboutFragment()).commit();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_logout:
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;

        }

        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".RegisterActivity"/>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"/>
    </application>
```

there's no error, it just skipped and redirected to MainActivity, where the HomeFragment is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are getting **getIsLogin()** in preferenceHelper **true** that's why it is redirecting
**Register Activity :**

```
    if(preferenceHelper.getIsLogin()){
                Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);
                this.finish();
    }
```

Just clear the preferences before you go to login page or redirect user to main activity if user us already login